# Rounding of double value VB.net

Tags: vb.net

When I execute the following code the variable **avg** stores **78.8751432..**

```
tot = Val(txttot1.Text) + Val(txttot2.Text) + Val(txttot3.Text) + Val(txttot4.Text) + Val(txttot5.Text) + Val(txttot6.Text) + Val(txttot7.Text) + Val(txttot8.Text)
avg = tot / pcount
lblcrtot.Text = tot
lblcravg.Text = avg
```

I need to round of the value as **78.875**

I tried out `Math.Round(3, avg)` but didn't work.

I need some suggestions

Answer (score 4):

You need to switch the arguments for `Math.Round()`

```
Math.Round(tot, 3)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx

Comment: You are right, I changed the arguments' order and the argument too **avg** was the right argument.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim rounded As Decimal = Decimal.Round( tot, 3)
```

Comment: Bas answer was better!